# Alterar propriedade de vários buttons simultaneamente

Tags: c#, button

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um projeto de uma clinica odontológica em c# no qual usa vários botoes dentro de uma picturebox para selecionar os dentes, por isso resolvi colocar vários buttons com certa opacidade e o resultado ficou muito satisfatório, o problema e que as propriedades de opacidade de um button só podem ser setadas no próprio código e não no menu propriedades do VS. Então para isso tenho que relacionar todos os buttons a picturebox, setar a location de cada um e setar sua cor e opacidade, nisso, fica um código muito extenso.Gostaria de saber se ao menos posso setar a cor e a opacidade dos buttons de uma vez só em apenas algumas linhas de código ao invés de repetir o mesmo para cada button.

Segue um pedaço do que fiz como exemplo, no total seriam 32 buttons, ficaria um código creio que eu desnecessariamente grande.

```
 button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightBlue);
        button1.Parent = pictureBox1;
        button1.Location = new Point(28, 90);
        button2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        button2.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightBlue);
        button2.Parent = pictureBox1;
        button2.Location = new Point(55, 90);
        button3.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        button3.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightBlue);
        button3.Parent = pictureBox1;
        button3.Location = new Point(80, 90);
        button4.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        button4.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightBlue);
        button4.Parent = pictureBox1;
        button4.Location = new Point(112, 90);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta os seus botoes num array e percorra o array. Mas apenas pode fazer isso para as propriedades com valores iguais:

```
var botoes = new[]{button1, button2, button3, button4 /*...*/};
foreach(var botao in botoes){
    botao.Parent = pictureBox1;
    botao.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    botao.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightBlue);
    //...
}
```

Outra forma de fazer o mesmo seria derivando de `Button` e setar as propriedades com valores por omissao.

```
public class BotaoTransparente : Button{
    public BotaoTransparente(Controll parent){
        Parent = parent;
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightBlue);
    }
}
```

Agora em vez de usar os botoes "normais" usa os seus

```
button1 = new BotaoTransparente(pictureBox1);
```

Comment: é bem isso que estou a procura, muito obrigado!!!!

Comment: nessa ultima parte da segunda sugestão, onde coloco o button1 = etc?
onde quer que eu o coloque da erro "inaccessible due to its protection level"

Comment: @GabrielArruda Certifique-se que a sua classe/campo é publica e o construtor também

Comment: tenho um duvida, ele deveria criar um novo botão no form ao invés de usar o button1 ja existente no form? na hora de executar a propriedades do button não são aplicadas e ele cria um novo button aleatório.

Comment: Voce tem que encontrar o seu botao na `toolbox`. Normalmente isso só é possível se tiver um construtor sem argumentos, para o botao aparecer na `toolbox` tem que fazer build do projecto.

É por este motivo que dei a primeira solucao, eu considero ela um pouco mais simples.

Comment: hmm, mas isso e uma coisa que não compreendi muito bem como isso funciona, tem algum lugar que mostre isso? o amigo do outro post disse a mesma coisa mas fiquei sem entender.

Comment: @GabrielArruda [Espero que a minha pergunta ajude](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161463/como-%C3%A9-que-posso-usar-o-meu-controlo-no-winforms/161466#161466)  e resposta

Comment: ajudou muito sim Bruno, muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela paciencia!!!!
a questão mesmo e que ele não apareceu na minha toolbox, se não, não estaria tendo toda esta duvida, mas para isso se eu não descobrir eu abro outro post, vlw!!!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma classe que herde de `button`, e implemente outra interface, e depois só dar `foreach` nos `this.Controls`.. algo tipo assim:

```
public interface iDentes{}

public class ButtonDentes : Button, iDentes {}
```

Use a  `ButtonDentes` no seu form ao invés de `Button` (para aparecer o componente da toolbox basta dar build no seu projeto)

Depois no seu form basta percorrer os `this.Controls`

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is ButtonDentes)
    {
        ((ButtonDentes)c).propriedade = xxxx;
    }
}
```