# Como adicionar controlos criados por mim na ToolBox do Visual Studio?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, toolbox

Eu criei um controlo para `WinForms`. Mas nao encontro o meu controlo na *toolbox*.

Como posso adicionar o meu controlo a *toolbox*?

Comment: @jbueno acho que fez bem em nao meter a tag de `c#`. O controlo pode ser feito em `VB.Net` por exemplo. Nao ha nenhuma linguagem associada a pergunta neste caso.

Comment: Exatamente. Por isso que eu removi.

Comment: Os votadores que expliquem como posso melhorar a minha pergunta.

Comment: Não foi eu quem votou negativo, mas ajustei sua publicação pra ficar um pouco melhor.

Comment: @jbueno Obrigado :)

Comment: Bruno, sua pergunta está meio confusa. Eu só entendi realmente o que desejava depois de ler a resposta.

Comment: De fato, só pela pergunta não é possível respondê-la, até é possível olhando a resposta, mas aí já foi respondida, ou seja, não parece ser uma pergunta. Eu reabro se a pergunta ficar em forma que todos possam responder, no momento ela não está clara.

Comment: @bigown Espero que esteja melhor agora

Comment: @BrunoCosta não, tirar informações não deixa a pergunta mais clara. O problema é que só conseguimos entender o que deseja fazer de fato lendo a resposta. tenho certeza que está claro na sua cabeça, até ajuda ficar claro lendo a resposta, mas a pergunta não dá todas informações necessárias para que a pessoa que quiser e entenda do assunto possa responder.

Comment: @bigown Que outras informacoes voce precisaria para responder a pergunta?

Comment: @BrunoCosta Se você colocasse apenas "**Como criar um botão customizado no Windowns Forms e adicionar ele na barra de TolBox do Visual Studio?**" ficaria mais simples de entender.

Comment: @BrunoCosta não sei, eu leio isso não entendo o que é necessário fazer aí. Quando eu li a resposta original, aí deu para entender o que queria, mas só com ela é que deu para entender. Eu entendo a intenção, mas faltou especificar melhor qual é o problema. Talvez uma imagem tivesse ajudado, não que precise, mas é uma forma de compensar a falta de melhor texto, tem muita pergunta que se salva por causa disto. Como você já sabia a resposta, pense em fazer de uma forma que você não soubesse, o que precisaria colocar para as pessoas entenderem, sem dar a resposta?

Comment: @bigown Sendo muito honesto já nao sei mais o que é preciso. Eu já consegui ajudar um utilizador e isso era tudo o que queria. Se a decisao da comunidade for fechar a pergunta ela que fique fechada...

Comment: @Randrade Eu agradeco a sugestao Randrade. O problema é que no seu ponto de vista essa é a pergunta ideal. Nao quer dizer que ela seja para outras pessoas. Outro problema também é que foi voce que teve o trabalho de fazer a pergunta dessa forma e nao eu...

Comment: @BrunoCosta Então, eu apenas dei uma sugestão de pergunta, não disse que era para fazer exatamente igual. Todavia, existem [188 perguntas](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=custom+toolbox+%5Bwinforms%5D) com um texto similar no SOen, então não creio que seja apenas meu ponto de vista. Porém, entendo o que está falando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faca o seu controlo (exemplo minimo):

```
class BotaoTransparente : Button
{
    public BotaoTransparente()
    {
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```

No visual studio 2015 os controlos sao automáticamente adicionados quando se faz build do projeto:

Tem que fazer build do projecto. PAra fazer build do projecto clique com o botao do lado direto do rato sobre o projecto e selecione `build`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para encontrar o toolbox vá a `View -> Toolbox`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando estiver a desenhar o seu forme procure o seu controlo e arraste-o para o form:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]